# PyroCMS get latest registered users

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I want to create a small widget which displays the last 3 user registrations in PyroCMS.
What I actually need more specifically is how to get the last 3 registered user IDs, displaying user data would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working this way:

```
$this->load->driver('Streams');
$params = array(
        'stream'        => 'profiles',
        'namespace'     => 'users',
        'limit'         => '3'
);
$entries = $this->streams->entries->get_entries($params);
```